# Wicket: add TextField / Panel dynamically

Tags: java, wicket

I want to add some `TextField` to a form dynamically and hide or show some of the onClick.

What I want to implement as image (its actually german so I explain it):
On the left side there are the days of the week (Monday, Tuesday, ... , Sunday). If u click the button with the arrow to the right direction the actuall week should hide and the next week shows up.

I stored an `Integer` that represent a cycle. So If in the database is a 3 I need to be able to click 3 times on the button "next week". (NOTE: this number can change dynamically). So If I change the number 3 to 5 I need 5 times this form.

I hope I described it "O.k", my english isn´t the best. Sorry for that.

[image: menu image]

What I´ve read:
First I need a panel where I add the `TextFields`, second I need a ListView which gets a list of Panels. But I don´t get how this works.. is this the right way to do this?

FormPanel:

```
public class FoodFieldPanel extends Panel {

public FoodFieldPanel(String id) {
    super(id);
    WebMarkupContainer foodFields = new WebMarkupContainer("foodFields");
    TextField monday = new TextField("monday");
    TextField tuesday = new TextField("tuesday");
    TextField wendnesday = new TextField("wendnesday");
    TextField thursday = new TextField("thursday");
    TextField friday = new TextField("friday");
    TextField saturday = new TextField("saturday");
    TextField sunday = new TextField("sunday");
    foodFields.add(monday);
    foodFields.add(tuesday);
    foodFields.add(wendnesday);
    foodFields.add(thursday);
    foodFields.add(friday);
    foodFields.add(saturday);
    foodFields.add(sunday);
    add(foodFields);
} 
}
```

Page:

```
public class FoodDetailPanel extends Panel {

public FoodDetailPanel(String id, final IModel<Category> catModel, boolean fieldsEnabled) {
    super(id, catModel);
    setOutputMarkupId(true);
    int cycle = 4;
    List<FoodFieldPanel> textFields = new ArrayList<FoodFieldPanel>();
    for (int a = 1; a <= cycle; a++) {
        textFields.add(new FoodFieldPanel("foodField"));
    }
    add(new ListView("test", textFields) {
        protected void populateItem(ListItem item) {
            FoodFieldPanel test = (FoodFieldPanel) item.getModelObject();
            add(test);
        }
    });
}
}
```

MarkupForPage:

```
<wicket:panel xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
<span wicket:id="test">
    <div wicket:id="foodField">

    </div>
</span> 
</wicket:panel>
```

As a first step I want to create the panel as often as I need it ..

Comment: Am I right that the screen layout never really changes and only a single week is shown at any one time?

Comment: yes only one week on time, but there are different strings inside the textfields

Comment: Okay, that makes the answer a lot simpler :)

Comment: for every week there a different strings inside the textfields (its a menu card of a restaurant), so later I need to load the strings of my database and put them into that fields.
I think I got what u said, I don´t need to create that panel more than one time. I just need the same form and only need to change the date and field content on click .. am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, given that your display is static and only the data behind it has to change, you can utilise the power of models. (I can't post a full solution, it would be too long but hopefully it'll show you the general idea.)

```
class WeekData {
   private String monday;
   private String tuesday;
   // and so on
}

class AllData {
  private final int minWeek;
  private final int maxWeek;
  private int currentWeek; // this is modified by clicking the arrows

  private Map<Integer, WeekData> weekMap;

  public IModel<WeekData> createDataModel() {
    return new IModel<WeekData>() {
       public WeekData getObject() {
         return weekMap.get( currentWeek );
       }
    }
  }

  public IModel<Integer> createWeekModel() {
    return new IModel<Integer>() {

       public Integer getObject() {
         return currentWeek;
       }
    }
  }

}
```

Your `FoodFieldPanel` initialisation will look like this:

```
public FoodFieldPanel(String id, IModel<AllData> model) {
  super(id);
  WebMarkupContainer foodFields = new WebMarkupContainer("foodFields", new CompoundPropertyModel( model.getObject().createDataModel() ) );
  TextField monday = new TextField("monday");
  TextField tuesday = new TextField("tuesday");
  //...
  foodFields.add(monday);
  foodFields.add(tuesday);
  //
  add(foodFields);
}
```

You'll also need to change the code for the arrows in a similar fashion, but the basic idea is that by using dynamic models you can replace the data behind the page without the display code even knowing about the logic. And you don't need the extra `ListView`. (Although I would personally store the days of the week in a `ListView` but I didn't want to complicate my answer even further.)

This kind of decoupling of display and model is one of Wicket's most powerful features so [it's worth learning as much about them as you can](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Working+with+Wicket+models).

Comment: hey thanks for your help, I gonna try this today and will post my solution later or tomorrow .

Comment: I don´t get why u use `model.getObject().createWeekModel()` while I could just do `model.getObject().createDataModel() `. What´s the use of getting a `model` of an `Integer`

Comment: @monti Sorry, that was a typo, of course I meant `getDataModel()`. The other model is for the arrows. (Fixed it.)

Comment: Im actually not sure about my implementation of my button. I increment the current page by 1, but I create a new panel every time. I guess that´s not the right way

`getPage().get("form").get("group").get("categoryTablePanel").get("foodFieldPanel").replaceWith(new FoodFields("foodFieldPanel", weekDataModel));`